# How to correctly authenticate server-sent-event endpoint with firebase auth?

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, server-sent-events

I am using firebase for authentication with my custom server. This server exposes an endpoint for client to subscribe to server-sent-events. I initially open connection via `new EventSource(myApi.com?:firebaseToken)` and validate this token via admin sdk on the server.

But I have few questions / concerns:

1. Is it secure to send firebase token as a url parameter like that?
2. What happens if user is connected to this event endpoint longer than lifetime of the token, i.e. token now becomes outdate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If the connection is encrypted, and the client trusts the server, then you can send whatever you want without problems.
2. The permissions granted by the token will expire in one hour.  The client will need to provide a new token before then.